# ¿Existe alguna forma de negar algo como isinstance() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, método

Para hacer más claro mi pregunta, pongo un ejemplo en código `R` que es el lenguaje en el que tengo un poco más de experiencia.
Supongamos que tengo la sencilla variable "a" que vale 5. En primer lugar quiero validar si es numérica utilizando is.numeric:

```
a <- 5
is.numeric(a)
[1] TRUE
```

Ahora bien, para checar si no es numérica, utilizamos un signo ! antes del método y obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
!is.numeric(a)
[1] FALSE
```

Mi pregunta es si es posible hacer algo así en Python, "negando" un método como isinstance() que sigue la estructura:

```
isinstance(variable, tipo)
```

Por ejemplo, si aplicamos negación a isinstance, obtengo:

```
a= 5
!isinstance(a, int)

"isinstance" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

No encontré ninguna información útil, por eso planteo mi pregunta. Si existe material que he pasado por alto, también apreciaría mucho me lo hicieran saber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El operador de negación en Python es `not`.

```
>>> a= 5
>>> not isinstance(a, int)
False
```

La admiración `!` no es un símbolo válido en Python, aunque sí puedes usarlo en ciertos intérpretes interactivos, como Jupyter Notebook o IPython. En ellos sirve para invocar comandos externos del operativo (shell), lo que explica el mensaje de error que has podido ver (quien no reconoce `isinstance` como un comando válido es el *shell*).

Comment: Gracias, ya te había dejado un comentario en respuesta al tuyo. Necesito salir un poco de mi caja de R, ya que en estos pequeños detalles se esconden grandes diferencias. Saludos.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera Como ves, decidí convertir mi comentario en respuesta para darle más visibilidad, por si hay más en tu caso. Puedes si quieres borrar el comentario que habías dejado en respuesta al mío, que ya no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La forma de negar en Python es directamente un `not` por ejemplo:

```
a = 5
print(isinstance(a, int))
print(not isinstance(a, int))

True
False
```

Lo que tienes que tener en cuenta son algunas particularidades de Python con respeto a R.  `is.numeric()` de R es una función de mayor nivel que `isinstance()` de Python, `isinstance()` verifica un objeto para ver si coincide con una determinada clase, y  en Python base, como en R, hay varias clases que pueden considerarse numéricas (de hecho hay más):

En R:

```
is.numeric(5.0) # TRUE
is.numeric(5L)  # TRUE
```

En Python

```
isinstance(5, int)   # TRUE
isinstance(5.0, int) # FALSE
```

El truco en Python es pasarle a `isinstance()` una lista con las clases a verificar, obviamente con aquellas que consideremos numéricas. podría ser algo así: `isinstance(5.0, (int, float))`, sin embargo algo más cómodo, es aprovechar el módulo `numbers` para saber  las clases que debemos considerar numéricas:

```
import numbers

def isnumeric(x):
  return isinstance(x, numbers.Number)

print(isnumeric(5))
print(isnumeric(5.0))

True
True
```

Comment: Gracias, como siempre. ¿Hay algo que no sepas? Je, je. Saludos.

Comment: Uf.. si tienes tiempo te cuento, je je. Ahora en serio, en mi caso, respondo para aprender también. Saludos.